# Evaluating $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}{(2\csc(x))^{17}dx}$

Tags: definite-integrals

> The integral $$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}{(2\csc(x))^{17}dx}$$
> is equal to:

> a)$\int_0^{ln(1+\sqrt2)}{2(e^u+e^{-u})^{16}du}$

> b)$\int_0^{ln(1+\sqrt2)}{2(e^u+e^{-u})^{17}du}$

> c)$\int_0^{ln(1+\sqrt2)}{2(e^u-e^{-u})^{16}du}$

> d)$\int_0^{ln(1+\sqrt2)}{2(e^u-e^{-u})^{17}du}$

---

**My Attempt**

The $(e^u - e^{-u})$ term just begs us to use $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$

So $$I=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}{\frac{2^{34}i}{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^{17}}dx}$$

Let

$u=ix$

$du=idx$

$$I=\int_{i\pi/4}^{i\pi/2}{\frac{2^{34}}{(e^{u}-e^{-u})^{17}}du}$$

The limits of the integral tell me that I'm not on the right track. Any help to evaluate the integral(preferably using complex numbers) is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.getpractice.com/questions/758965 does this help

Comment: That was a nice one. Is there any hope for using complex numbers?

Comment: i dont think so. I have seen this question in (iit jee) i tried your method and it didnt work.

Comment: Yeah same. I thought there has to be an approach using complex numbers. 2 and $e^u-e^{-u}$ are wanting me to do it.

Comment: using complex numbers in integration is not there in jee syllabus so i guess that aproach can be ruled out

Comment: But $i$ just vanishes. I feel like we are both missing something. Lets wait for someone to point that out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112266/discussion-between-datboi-and-quantum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Quantum noted, substituting $du=\csc xdx$ proves a) is correct. Expressing $\csc x$ in terms of this $u$ doesn't use complex eponentials, despite their role in their formula for $\sin x$.

[Bioche's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules) suggest instead substituting $v=\cos x$, giving $\int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}2^{17}(1-v^2)^{-9}dv$. While this doesn't easily relate to the original problem (it doesn't help you think to try $u=\tfrac12\ln\tfrac{1+v}{1-v}$), it does make a role for complex exponentials look even less likely, because of an obvious (very tedious) integral evaluation strategy over $\Bbb R$ in partial fractions.

Why does this problem *not* call for complex exponentials, even though trigonometry is definable in terms of it? The simplest answer I can give is that there's actually a real-only way to relate real exponentials to complex ones, although you can rewrite it in terms of complex numbers [if you really want to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function#History). Define the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function)$$\operatorname{gd}x:=2\arctan\tanh\tfrac{x}{2}$$and [its inverse the Lambertian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function#Gudermannian_and_lambertian)$$\operatorname{lam}x:=2\operatorname{artanh}\tan\tfrac{x}{2},$$odd functions which satisfy (among other things)$$\operatorname{gd}^\prime x=\operatorname{sech}x,\,\operatorname{lam}^\prime x=\sec x.$$If it seems weird that this works, notice$$t=\tan\frac{y}{2}=\tanh\frac{z}{2}\implies\sin y=\tanh z=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\,\cos y=\operatorname{sech}z=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}.$$Famously, [integrating odd powers of the (co)secant reduces to the Lambertian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed#Higher_odd_powers_of_secant) (whereas with their hyperbolic counterparts the Gudermannian comes up). So the large odd power of $17$ hides the fact that you may as well be asking why integrant $\csc x$ doesn't use complex exponentials.

Comment: So I rather stick with simpler methods instead of learning these new hard ones. Also thanks for introducing these new functions to me. I'll certainly do some research regarding this.

Comment: @DatBoi You have a healthy attitude. My answer doesn't so much provide new techniques as provide a new perspective on why techniques have the effects they do.

Comment: Thanks. I always wanted to explore the extent to which I can use my concepts to solve a question, before stumbling upon such ridiculous, new stuff. I try to learn as much as I can when I'm free. My exams are in the near future, so its not the right time to learn new things.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} (2 \csc x)^{17} dx$$
Let
$$\csc x+\cot x=e^{u}, \csc x- \cot x= e^{-u} \implies 2 \csc x=(e^{u}+ e^{-u}), 2 \cot x=e^u- e^{-u},$$
also,
$$-2\cot x \csc x dx=(e^u+e^{-u}) du \implies dx=-\frac{2du}{(e^u+e^{-u})}$$
$$x=\pi/4 \implies u=\ln (1+\sqrt{2}), ~~x=\pi/2 \implies u=0$$
Then, $$I =\int_{0}^{\ln(1+\sqrt{2})} 2(e^u+e^{-u})^{16}du.$$
Finally, $(a)$ option is correct.

Comment: Every method revolves around using the basic identity $1+\cot^2(x)=\csc^2(x)$. Thank you for your efforts.